# Scripts launched from crontab don't work as if I run as self

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron, pulseaudio

I have a script on my home theater PC running Ubuntu 22. The purpose of this script is to check

1. When was mouse/keyboard activity last seen?
2. Is there active audio playing (music or video)
   and then it determines if the htpc is idle or not, and relays this information back to my home automation server.

I have a "helper" script that fires this up in a tmux session (mainly so I can attach and debug since I have it dump output to the terminal) at boot.

If I run this script as the main user (htpc), then it works great. When it launches from the crontab, pulse audio states that there is no pulse audio daemon running. Checking `ps` shows that both run as htpc.

Output of running directly from a terminal (I'm SSH'd in)

```
htpc@htpc:~/Documents$ ps aux | grep -i idle
htpc        8397  0.0  0.0  11308  3736 ?        Ss   00:03   0:00 tmux new-session -d -s idle-script exec /home/htpc/Documents/report_idle_to_hass.sh
htpc        8398  0.0  0.0  10100  4012 pts/2    Ss+  00:03   0:00 /bin/bash /home/htpc/Documents/report_idle_to_hass.sh
htpc        8455  0.0  0.0   9208  2180 pts/3    S+   00:03   0:00 grep --color=auto -i idle
```

Output of running from a crontab job:

```
htpc@htpc:~/Documents$ ps aux | grep -i idle
htpc        6720  0.0  0.0  11304  3604 ?        Ss   23:57   0:00 tmux new-session -d -s idle-script exec /home/htpc/Documents/report_idle_to_hass.sh
htpc        6721  0.0  0.0  10100  3988 pts/2    Ss+  23:57   0:00 /bin/bash /home/htpc/Documents/report_idle_to_hass.sh
htpc        6748  0.0  0.0   9208  2416 pts/3    S+   23:57   0:00 grep --color=auto -i idle
```

Visually, I don't see why one works and another doesn't.

tmux output of a manually started (me via ssh) instance:

```
Counter overflowed: No
[][]
Counter overflowed: No
[][]
```

Note that the [][] simply is a response from my home automation server. It's an empty response because the state did not change. It will populate with previous state information if there was a change.

tmux output of a crontab-started instance:

```
Counter overflowed: Yes
[][]
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
Counter overflowed: Yes
[][]
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

Crontab entry (running crontab -e):
`@reboot exec /home/htpc/Documents/start_idle_report.sh`

I'll give the script giving the error first, the only part that doesn't work is the `pacmd` command. It does successfully grab the window name and keyboard/mouse last input time. Only `pacmd` has issues.
check_idle.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0

# Set the timeout value to consider device idle
time_to_be_idle_ms=60000

audio_check="`exec pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep \"state: RUNNING\"`"
idle_time="`exec xprintidle`"
current_app="`exec xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname`"

if [ -z "$audio_check" ]
then
        if [ "$idle_time" -gt "$time_to_be_idle_ms" ]
        then
                if [[ "$current_app" == *"Frigate"* ]]
                then
                        # No audio, idle time, but cameras are in focus
                        echo "No"
                else
                        # No audio, idle time, and cameras aren't in focus
                        echo "Yes"
                fi
        else
                # No audio playing, but idle time not met
                echo "No"
        fi
else
        # Playing audio
        echo "No"
fi
```

start_idle_report.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# Kick off the report script
if [[ "`ps aux | grep -i report_idle_to_hass | wc -l`" -eq "1" ]];
then
        tmux new-session -d -s "idle-script" "exec /home/htpc/Documents/report_idle_to_hass.sh"
fi
```

report_idle_to_hass.sh (some info redacted):

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

submit_state() {
        # This function sends the desired output to my server
}

submit_state "No"
last_state="No"
counter=0
while [ true ]
do
        idle_check="`/home/htpc/Documents/check_idle.sh`"
        if [[ "$idle_check" != "$last_state" ]]
        then
                echo "States changed: $idle_check"
                submit_state "$idle_check"
                last_state="$idle_check"
                counter=0
        else
                counter=$((counter+1))
        fi

        if [ "$counter" -gt 10 ]
        then
                echo "Counter overflowed: $last_state"
                submit_state "$last_state"
                counter=0
        fi
        sleep 2
done
```

I looked up how pulse figures out what to connect to: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/FAQ/

It lists several environment variables. When I look with printenv, there are no display related or pulse related variables set.
I do not have a ~/.pulse folder to contain the config, and the default pulse file in /etc/pulse is empty (nothing but comments in there).

How is it finding a pulse server when I run it but not in crontab?

I thought maybe it was a path issue (even though I define the paths in the script)

```
htpc@htpc:~/Documents$ which pacmd
/usr/bin/pacmd
```

I have tried it with the 'exec' removed and added. Tried 'exec' when I found another question on stack overflow that suggested using exec because it was firing off the script with a 'sh -c' instead, and I figured this might be the problem, but it did not fix it.

I expected the behavior to be identical to me sshing in and simply typing the tmux command myself, but for some reason when started via a crontab job it does not work.

Feels a lot like the commands are being executed as a different user, or some variable issue.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1207581/pacmd-why-doesnt-it-work-from-cron

Comment: Wow i don't know how you found that. That looks like it might be the issue. That variable is not one of the variables listed in the pulse audio documentation... Thanks, I'll try when I get home

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that it is running as cron and not as you, then you need to place your cron entries in a user-specific crontab under /var/spool/cron/crontabs (Ubuntu MATE 20.04), not in the main crontab.